# -bash: /wlpfo/sources/build/ant.sh: /bin/ksh^M: bad interpreter: no such file or directory

Tags: windows, bash

I have the problem that I get the above message when I run `ant.sh`. I can use `dos2unix ant.sh` to solve the problem with this specific file. But I get the same message for every `.sh` file. And here lies the problem: The company where I work has (of course) a lot of such files and I can't really change all of them. If for nothing else, then because other people don't seem to have the same problem as I have. Also I don't even know which `.sh` files are used when I do `./ant.sh`.

Is there some way to get around this problem?

Comment: Are these files version-controlled? I remember `git` has some config/options to convert to unix format. This way configuring your repo should change all files on commit and this problem will go away.  I think removing this line-end chars will not cause problems to windows users so it should be safe. Its been a while since I used `git` and will need to google to find the details

Comment: Yes, I that's the solution. (Someone found it already)